# Julia: How to make a matrix in for loop

Tags: arrays, matrix, julia

I'm a newbie to Julia. Before then, I used Matlab.
For the Matlab case, I wrote commands to make the matrix in the for loop, as follows:

`for i=1:1:100; k(i,:)=i.^2; end`

I typed the same commands in Julia, but it didn't work.
Furthermore, I tried other commands as follows:

```
n=100;
k = Array{Int64, n};
for i in 1:n;
    k[i]= i;
end;
```

However, the error happened as follows:

```
MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::Type{Array{Int64, 10}}, ::Int64, ::Int64)
```

How to make a matrix in for loop in Julia?

Comment: You can use multi-dimensional array comprehension in Julia too. For example for a matrix: `[i^2+j for i in 1:100, j in 1:10]`

Comment: Why not simply `(1:100).^2` either in Julia or in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this approach:

```
julia> n = 100;

julia> k = Array{Int64, 1}(undef, n);

julia> for i in 1:n
           k[i]=i
       end

julia> k
100-element Vector{Int64}:
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   ⋮
```

The problem with your code is where you wrote `k = Array(Int64, n)`. In Julia, you can define an initialized `Vector` using one of these approaches:

```
julia> Array{Int64, 1}(undef, 5)
5-element Vector{Int64}:
        1052672
 17592455528464
    68987912208
  2137636676096
              0

julia> Vector{Int64}(undef, 5)
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 2137626020784
 2137626020816
 2137626020848
 2137626020880
          3063

julia> zeros(Int64, 5)
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0

julia> ones(Int64, 5)
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

In the above, I created some initialized `Vector`s with specific attributes, all with length `5`. Note that the meaning of `Array{Int64, 1}(undef, 5)` can be translated to create an object of type `Array` with the number of dimensions equal to `1` (a Vector in fact) and put `5` `undef`ined values of type `Int64` in it.
But if you want to make a `Matrix` (considering the way you wrote `k[i]= i`, it seems to me that you want an `nx1` dimensional Matrix), then you can do the following:

```
julia> n = 100;

julia> k = Array{Int64, 2}(undef, n, 1);

julia> for i in 1:n
           k[i]=i
       end

julia> k
100×1 Matrix{Int64}:
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
  10
   ⋮
```

Note that the type of `k` is `Matrix` with element type `Int64`. using the following approaches, you can create an initialized `Matrix`:

```
julia> Array{Int64, 2}(undef, 5, 1)
5×1 Matrix{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5

julia> Matrix{Int64}(undef, 5, 1)
5×1 Matrix{Int64}:
             1
             4
 2137623855824
 2137623855888
             0

julia> zeros(5, 1)
5×1 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0

julia> ones(5, 1)
5×1 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
```

In all above, `5, 1` specifies the matrix's dimension.

---

## Additional Note

Note that you can assign values to an `nxn` Matrix (or even a high dimensional `Array`) using single indexing:

```
julia> k = [5; 7;;8; 9]
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 5  8
 7  9

julia> for i in eachindex(k)
           k[i]=i
       end

julia> k
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  3
 2  4

julia> k
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  3
 2  4
```

In the above, the [`eachindex(k)`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.eachindex) creates a `UnitRange` which contains values from 1 up to 4 (since the `k` has 4 elements) and is iterable.

Comment: You gave me a perfect answer, it helped to solve the problem. Especially, Your additional example was really helpful. Thank you, Shayan. Happy new year :)

Comment: @ManuHan, YW! Great to hear that! If you can't follow and understand any piece of the above explanation and examples (since you said you're new to Julia), mention them in the comments, and I'll add further explanations for you. Happy new year, and enjoy [Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want nx1 matrix you can also use comprehension with 2 indexes:

```
julia> [i*i for i ∈ 1:5, j ∈ 1:1]
5×1 Matrix{Int64}:
  1
  4
  9
 16
 25
```